# Parent Hidden but Child element is still visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation where my parent element has a style as visibility : hidden and the inner image has `visibility : visible`

My expectation is because the parent has visibility hidden the child should not be visible. I have seen questions similar to this before but I am expecting some detailed explanation

Please refer the below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/raviteja_avvari/x20hhje9/

Comment: .visiible ?? double ii?

Comment: it is working fine, may I know the browser on which you are getting this issue

Comment: It is working fine.. i have created a fiddle for this check it https://jsfiddle.net/tu5w6z52/1/

Comment: Its only a typo, as pointed by @captainsac

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because you are having a visible element inside an invisible one, to control this you will need to create a nexted class selection

```
.parent .child {
Css codes
}
```

Finally, use display:none; instead of visibility